# How to install sqlite from source on Mac?

Tags: sqlite

I have seen [this question on the source code of SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615213/where-can-one-find-source-archives-of-old-sqlite-versions). However, I can not make sense on how to build SQLite on my Mac OS 10.6 from scratch, esp. an old version. What steps do I need?

Comment: This is not quite programming related. I’ll shift it to http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite project recommends using their [amalgamation package](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) which bundles in source files for dependencies.

> The amalgamation and the sqlite3.h
>   header file are available on the
>   download page as a file named
>   sqlite-amalgamation-X_X_X.zip where
>   the X's are replaced by the
>   appropriate version number.appropriate version number.

You can change the URL for the current amalgamation download to get the older version that you want.

Once you have that, open up the zip file or tar.gz (aka tarball) download. The `INSTALL` file gives instructions, but they're standard for most source build downloads:

1. `cd` into the source directory
2. Run the configuration script to make makefiles for your environment: `./configure`
3. Run `make`
4. Run `make install` -- typically using sudo to gain the permissions you need: `sudo make install`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take a look at [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) project. You could build SQLite from sources using MacPorts.

Comment: thanks, I know MacPorts. I would like to get an old version of sqlite to make some changes, and experiment with it. do you know how to access their CVS repository. Also, it would be useful to me to have some old ("simpler") version of the project.